# Connect to https without a certificate

Tags: https

I'd like to connect to my website via https urls also if at the moment I don't have any certificate. I want to do this to test the URL structure on all pages. Is this possible?

If I digit https://www.example.com I see a blank page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no way to get around needing a certificate for an https connection, however you can go for the free option of a self-signed certificate. Have a look into a service such as http://www.selfsignedcertificate.com/ to get the key and certificate created for your website.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I don't understand if it's necessary to have a self signed certificate to visit my site via https, or if I can do it also without it. I can do it without it, how can I?

Comment: You definitely need a certificate to make it happen. Self-signed are fine for testing and don't incur a cost, which is why it may be useful for your own investigations before committing to the cost of a real one. But again, yes, you do need a certificate to visit your site via https.